# What does mean ace::/64 address space in Azure?

Tags: azure, ip-address

A listing in one of Azure networks reveals following address space ace::/64

**What it is?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the short form for an IPv6 address. The extended form would be `ace:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`, however, blocks with 0 can be shortened with the double colon, so the result is `ace::`. The `/64` means, that the address block marked by this address contains 2^64 addresses (an IPv6 address has 128 bits, and in this case 64 bits describe the network, and the other 64 can be assigned to actual devices in the network).